# get picture from media library using file name in windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I want to get a picture from media library using the file name, is it possible?

There's a method called
`mediaLibrary.GetPictureFromToken()`
is there a connection between token and file name?

Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you query [`MediaLibrary.Pictures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.pictures.aspx) to find the one you want? And then obtain it that way?

Comment: How do you make a query to do this?

Comment: I ended up searching through all pictures in media library with the picture name