# How to retrieve an image from WP7 photo library?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm developing an application where the user can add photos from windows phone 7 photo library and assign them to a particular view. To do this I save the OriginalFileName on the database (LINQ to SQL). Later I want to recover the photo and load it into the view. Do you know what I can do? currently I have this code but does not work.

When the user has selected the picture I keep his name in the variable fileName:

```
private void photoChooserTask_Completed (object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage ();
    e.OriginalFileName = fileName;
    image.SetSource (e.ChosenPhoto);
    this.Thumbnail.Source = image;
    this.Thumbnail.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
}
```

Later, when the user wants to save this setting I save the fileName in database.

This is the code when I load the view that must contain the photo.

```
imgSource var = new BitmapImage (new Uri (picture.Url, UriKind.Absolute));
item.LeftImage.Source = imgSource;
```

Where `picture.Url` contains the filename.

Any idea? I saw on the internet that you can keep the whole image, but give it the best possible.

Comment: Have you looked at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9235928/get-picture-from-media-library-using-file-name-in-windows-phone ?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is save the picture returned from the `PhotoChooserTask` in the IsolatedStorage.
You will then be able to load it when needed.

Here is [how to Read and Save Images](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-Images).

Comment: I was reading this article, but the problem I see is that if the user selects 100 photos, this means that 100 photos have been duplicated in the system?

For example, iOS photos have a unique link to access them without duplicating them.

Comment: Ok then another way to do this would be to use the `PhotoChooserTask` to let the user select the picture but only save the 'FileName'. Then you will have to browse the `MediaLibrary` pictures and search for the corresponding file. Take a look at here to see how to browse the `MediaLibrary`: http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/accessing-pictures-media

Comment: I done what you say, but the name that return PhotoChooseTask don't correspond to the name of the file, for exemple, if I choose a photo from PhotoChooserTask the name that it returns is "\\Applications\\Data\\6956F809-3F84-4E8B-B993-AF7161B075DE\\Data\\PlatformData\\PhotoChooser-cf0ba449-869e-464b-b174-2a9c5105f472.jpg" but in MediaLibrary the name is "paris.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

For what you need is to get the picture by browsing the MediaLibrary without using PhotoChooserTask, because as you experienced, the file name might not be the same if you use different methods.

For the custom MediaLibrary browsing interface, you could refer to this codeplex project:

https://multiphotochooser.codeplex.com/